# Fade out message after 10 seconds, clearing the input elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm displaying a message (#final_msg) after the user submits the form. What I want to do is that, after 15 seconds, the message (#final_msg) should fade out, clearing away [or fading out] the text in the input elements as well. Is it possible to do this?

```
else {
                        //create post data
                      var postData = { 
                        "name" : $("#name").val(),
                        "email" : $("#email").val(),
                        "msg" : $("#msg").val(),
                        "origin" : $("#origin").val()
                      };

                      //make the call
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "test.php",
                        data: postData, //send it along with your call
                        success: function(response){
                            $('#final_msg').fadeIn();

                        }
                      });
                }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
 $('#final_msg').fadeOut();
 $('#name, #email, #msg, #origin').val('')
}, 10000 );
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there any way to set the value of the input elements to their default values? For example, 'Your Name' as set in the HTML.

Comment: iterate through the object with a `for..in` and set the value using postData object.

Answer (score 47):

If you're on jQuery 1.4, you can use the [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function:

```
$('#final_msg').fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 5):

You should look into the [JavaScript setTimeout() method](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). With it, you may execute some function after a specific number of milliseconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#final_msg').fadeOut();}, 10000);
```

Besides the fading, you may clear all inputs in that function, e.g. by using $(':input').val("") and $(':input').removeAttr("checked") for radio buttons and checkboxes respectively (if there are any that is).